# Hibernate simple query to slow

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate on a Java project, but when i get all the entity Ids, this query takes like 5 minutes.

I use this function:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Long> findAllIDs() {
        log.debug("getting Ids de todos los cuesionarios iniciales.");
        try {
            return (List<Long>) this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().getNamedQuery("Cuestionarioinicial.findAllIDs").list();
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            log.error("get failed", re);
            throw re;
        }
    }
```

and the NamedQuery is:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Cuestionarioinicial.findAllIDs", query = "SELECT c.id FROM Cuestionarioinicial c")
```

What's the problem? Thanks.

Comment: It depends on various factors.which database you are using,how many records exist in table.Is id column is indexed or primary key. except this how much memory your application is taking and what is memory of your database server.

Comment: ...not to mention that it really doesn't make sense to find all ids. You'll never need all of them at the same time in a real application, and if you need to do something to all of them, they would be handled in a different way, such as batching.